# Can I use Parameters of a method invoked within an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, parameters

This is in the `main()` method:

```
Movie[] list = new Movie[6];

list[0] = new Animated(.25, 700.000, "Mulan", "Barry Cook", 1998, 15.000);
list[1] = new Animated(.23, 45.000, "TMNT", "Steve Barron", 1990, 12.000);
list[2] = new Documentary(12, 7.000, "Nixon", "Oliver Stone", 1995, 50.000);
list[3] = new Documentary(10, 4.500, "JFK", "Oliver Stone", 1991, 35.000);
list[4] = new Drama(3.500, 8.25, "Belly", "Hype Williams", 1998, 20.000);
list[5] = new Drama(4.500, 9.00, "42", "Brian Helgeland", 2013, 16.000);

System.out.print(menu());
System.out.print("Select and menu option 1-5: ");
choice = input.nextInt();
do
{
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1: movieList(list);
        break;
```

and I'm calling the `movieList(list)` method which exists within the class outside `main`:

```
public static void movieList(Movie[] a)
{
    System.out.printf("\n\n%-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s", "TITLE", "YEAR",
    "REVENUE", "PROFIT", "CATEGORY");
    System.out.printf("\n\n%-10s", Movie[0].getTitle());
}
```

This is the method I am calling in `case 1`, how I have been trying to use one Parameter and I get "cannot find symbol" error with the pointer at Movie.
I have been searching and I am beginning to think I cannot access this value this way.

Answer (score 4):

The name of your `Movie[]` parameter in your `movieList` method is `a`, so try using `a[0].getTitle()` instead of `Movie[0].getTitle()`. Parameters in a method are always accessed by it's name, not it's type.